# C Programming. Using fopen fclose for text file operations

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

I am opening a text file and processing word count function to count words and closing a file.
Next, I open the same file again and store it in the array with limit to word count value in an array.

Here, if I use fopen and fclose just once like in line 1 and 16, my program does not work. But if I open it (line 1) process it then close it (line 10) and open it again (line 12) for second process, my program works. Does it mean that fopen can only handle one process at a time and I have to open it again for second process?

```
1. fptrr = fopen(fname,"r"); // open the text file in read mode
2. 
3.  if (fptrr == NULL) {//if file name does not match
4.       printf("Error: No such file or directory");
5.       return -1;
6.     }
7. 
8. wordCount += countWords(fptrr); //run word count function and get the value of total words
9. 
10. fclose(fptrr); // close the file
11. 
12. fptrr = fopen(fname,"r");
13. for(int i=0;i<wordCount;i++){ // define size of loop equal to words in a file
14.    fscanf(fptrr, "%s", fileArray[i]); //scan and store in array
15. }
16. fclose(fptrr);
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `countWords()`?

Comment: After reading through the file the first time, you should be using `fseek` to return to the beginning of the file to process it again. Your question about fopen only handling one process, I find very confusing. Could you clarify?

Comment: Or Use [rewind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do whatever you want to the file while it is open.

I suspect your problem is that you are reading to the end of the file in one set of operations and then you try and read the file again while you are at the end. Look for the [rewind()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) function

To rewind to the start of the file just call `rewind(fptrr);` after the first countwords. Alternately you can call `fseek(fptrr, 0L, SEEK_SET)` but rewind() is clearer.

Note that closing the file and re-opening it automatically resets the file to read form the start which is why your new version works.